# How can I show text that is hidden on mouseover?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="clients">
<h1> Clients </h1>
<div class="mnlaownrs">
  <img src="img/img.png" width="226" height="" alt="manilaowners"></img><br>
  <a href="#" class="mnlacaption">
    <h4>ManilaOwners</h4>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
```

...and this is my CSS:

```
.mnlaownrs {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #544334;
    height: 82px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a.mnlacaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 236px;
}


a.mnlacaption:hover {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    width: 236px;
    height: 86px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.90);
    text-indent: center;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

How do I hide the text for `.mnlacaption` if it's in its normal state, but make it show on hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `a.mnlacaption` to initially be `display:none` (hidden), then when the containing `div`, `.mnlaownrs`, is in `hover` state, change the style to `display:block`

```
.mnlaownrs a.mnlacaption
{
display:none;
}

.mnlaownrs:hover a.mnlacaption
{
display:block;
}
```

Alternatively if you wish to not affect the rest of your page position when this element is hidden, use `visibility` instead:

```
.mnlaownrs a.mnlacaption
{
visibility:hidden;
}

.mnlaownrs:hover a.mnlacaption
{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: You would need some jQuery for that. Since it really messes up accessbility with display:none. Most browsers/screenreaders will not see it as content then. And HOVER on elements dont work in older browsers. But this effect could be done easy with some jQuery :)

Comment: @Marco - How old are we talking? I've been using `hover` on divs/table cells for a good while. Using jQuery just opens up the discussion of whether or not the browser theyre running has javascript enabled. Furthermore, OP never specified a javascript or jQuery solution.

Comment: I would have used visibility: hidden so that the owner's size do not change when the caption is hidden, which will happen with display: none.

Comment: @John Riche - Thanks John, added your suggestion to the answer

Comment: @Curst - IE6 and in some cases IE7 if i remember correctly (i know they are old and all that - just wanted to point it out). Still its important you atleast consider that screenreadsers/google searchbots etc migh not index the hidden text :)

Comment: -1. if the element is initially display: none; hover will never be initiated as the element is not on the page.

Comment: @Rikudo - its the parent element that has the hover effect, so it should still work :)

Comment: @Rikudo - Don't agree with your -1 there. As @Marco's pointed out, I think you've misread my syntax and comments in my answer. Its the parent element which has the `:hover` state.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.mnlacaption {
   text-indent:-9999px;
}


a.mnlacaption:hover {
   text-indent:0;
}
```

Should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.mnlaownrs {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #544334;
    height: 82px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: none; 
}
```

and on `:hover` make it `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.mnlacaption {

    visibility: hidden;
}
a.mnlacaption:hover {

    visibility: visible;
}
```

?